# como puedo editar datos de combo dependiente en ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

los combos que son dependiente del  $("#modulo")  son:        $('#semana').val(objProgramacion.semana) ,   $('#grupo').val(objProgramacion.idgrupo);
                  , $('#horario').val(objProgramacion.idhorario);
                         y $('#dias').val(objProgramacion.iddia);

$('.btnEditar').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
        var btnClickeado = $(this);
        var id = btnClickeado.data('id');
        var parametros = {
        id: id,
                task: 'get'
        };
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                data: parametros,
                url: 'ProgramacionAjax.php',
                success: function (data) {

```
            var objProgramacion = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('#hdnId').val(objProgramacion.codprogramacion);
                    $('#gestion').val(objProgramacion.idgestion);
                    $('#docente').val(objProgramacion.iddocente);
                    $('#materia').val(objProgramacion.idmateria);
                    $('#grupo').val(objProgramacion.idgrupo);
                    $('#horario').val(objProgramacion.idhorario);
                    $('#dias').val(objProgramacion.iddia);
                    $('#aula').val(objProgramacion.idaula);
                    $('#semana').val(objProgramacion.semana);
                    $('#Modulo').val(objProgramacion.modalidad);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            }
    });
```

});

aqui llamo los otros combo dependiente cuando empiezo registrar

$('#Modulo').change(function () {
                    var selectValor = '#' + $(this).val();
                    $('#entorno').children('div').hide();
                    $('#entorno').children(selectValor).show();

```
                $('#Modulo option:selected').each(function () {

                    id_materia = $(this).val();
                    $.post("includes/combo.php", {id_materia: id_materia}, function (data) {
                        $('#dias').html(data);
                    });
                    $.post("includes/combo2.php", {id_materia: id_materia}, function (data) {
                        $('#grupo').html(data);

                    });
                    $.post("includes/combo4.php", {id_materia: id_materia}, function (data) {

                        $('#horario').html(data);

                    });
                });
            });
```